# Looking for a smart way to hide/show groups of markers by category with Google Maps in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm looking for a way in the google maps SDK for android apps to add markers/polygons to a map "layer" or "group" and then hide/show those groups of map objects.

For instance.
a) call a function that adds 20 markers to a mapview in a grouped container (I don't know what/if google maps sdk has this, so I dont know what word to use here)

b) show that layer/group/container

c) time passes, the user browses the map for a bit

d) the user clicks a button and now we want to hide that layer/group/container

I might have 3 to 10 different groups of markers/polygons that I would want to hide/show.  I can think of brute force ways to do this, and some smart ways, but I'd like to use smart features of an SDK if available.  Layers (or something like) for example, if they exist.

Comment: maybe you need cluster? [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/marker-clustering)

Comment: Clusters were the closest feature I found.